# Finding UMVUE of a parameter in form of probability of discrete random variables

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, umvue, complete-statistics

We have $X$ and $Y$ as independent discrete random variables both in ${1, 2, ...}$.

Their pmf's are:

$f(x|\alpha)=P(X=x)=\alpha(1-\alpha)^{x-1}, x=1, 2, ...$
$f(y|\beta)=P(Y=y)=-\frac{1}{\log\beta}\frac{(1-\beta)^{y}}{y}, y=1, 2, ...$
$\alpha, \beta \in (0, 1)$

Given that $\frac{1-\alpha}{1-\beta}=\frac{1}{2}$ --- (*),

find a complete sufficient statistic $T(X, Y)$ for $(\alpha, \beta)$ and use it to find an UMVUE of $\theta=P(X>Y)$ without deriving an explicit expression of $\theta$.

**My attempt**

The joint pmf of $X, Y$ is found by multiplying the two pmf's.
$f(x, y|\alpha, \beta)=\frac{-\alpha}{y(1-\alpha)\log\beta}e^{x\log(1-\alpha)+y\log(1-\beta)}$

Further massaging using the constraint (*), the joint pmf becomes $f(x, y|\alpha, \beta)=\frac{-2^{y+1}\alpha}{y(1-\alpha)\log\beta}e^{(x+y)\log(1-\alpha)}$ which is an exponential family with natural parameter as just $\log(1-\alpha)$ and natural statistic $(x+y)$.
It is a complete sufficient statistics due to $\log(1-\alpha)$ being in $(-\infty, 0)$ which contains an open 1-D interval.

However, I am not sure how to proceed in finding a function of $(X+Y)$ that will give $\theta$ when being taken expectation of, to derive the UMVUE.

Taking the expectation of indicator can give a probability i.e.
$E[I(X>Y)]=E[I(X-Y>0)]=P(X>Y)=\theta$, however, I do not know how to use a function to map $X+Y$ into $X-Y$.

Comment: Your UMVUE is $P(X>Y\mid X+Y)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom How should I reason with it? Taking expectation: $E[P(X>Y\mid X+Y)]=\sum_{t>1}P(x>y\mid x+y)P(x+y=t)$, how is it equal to $P(X>Y)$ in the end?

Comment: It is simply $E\,P[X>Y\mid T]=E\,E[I(X>Y)\mid T]=E[I(X>Y)]=P(X>Y)$ with $T=X+Y$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Oh I see! In this case the complete sufficient statistic is still $X+Y$ right?

Comment: Yes, and that guarantees that the Rao-Blackwellized estimator $P(X>Y\mid X+Y)$ is the UMVUE.